# Access Violation when starting debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio, access-violation

I added an event handler to one of my forms. Nothing complicated, only a textbox click event and .Text property set. Now when I try to run my application, everything still complies and starts to run for a second or two but then debugging just stops. This is in my debug output:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException' in mscorlib.dll
SIOS Open Failed
ReadProperty<T>(CalibrationFile)
Exception thrown: 'System.NotImplementedException' in myappname.exe
The program '[3300] myappname.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
```

I did some googling and the only thing that I found that makes any sense at all was someone who'se antivirus was interfering and causing a similar problem. Has anyone seen this before? I'm not running any antivirus aside from whatever Windows has on it's own.

Something to note: Visual Studio is running as Administrator. (hardware controllers that could break expensive equipment if this isn't the case) Now, this doesn't matter during debug as this hardware isn't actually connected but the check will not let the application run if it is not "as administrator."

Comment: Show your event handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have a line of code containing `throw new System.NotImplementedException();`.

Find that line, then put something useful there instead.

Comment: Ahh yeah you're entirely right. My eyes went straight to the 'access violation' and I skimmed right over that. There was a second event handler (also a click event) that I hadn't filled yet and somehow it was firing off before that user control was even visible. Do you know why debugging stopped instead of breaking on that line?

Comment: Have you set you debugger to stop on exceptions?

Comment: Yes - and it normally does stop on this type of exception which is why I don't get why it didn't this time.